# NLC and BOT flow integration

Tags: watson

We are building Chat BOT using Watson ecosystem. I am new to the topic.
If my application wants to uses NLC for obtaining the class and using this class, if i want to start  a pre-cofigured  conversation flow with the user,  should the application make another call to Conversation service? Or Can the NLC start it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Conversation service includes the NLC service.

There were two services in Bluemix to create a chatbot: NLC and Dialog service. Last July, IBM released the Conversation service that includes both NLC and Dialog services. The Dialog was deprecated and the NLC isn't updated since April'16, so I think it is going to be deprecated too.

The Conversation service is newer and updated, it has a lot more features and it is cheaper. You should use it instead of NLC.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Danilo. This completely make sense.